# How come the AutoSum command is not working?

Tags: excel, vba

When I use the AutoSUM the sub exits and I need to hit the Enter Key manually. I tried to hard code the Enter Key but once the code gets to the Application.CommandBars... the code still exits the sub.

Thank you all in advance.

I have the following code:

```
For r = fRows + 1 To ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.count
If Cells(r, 3).Value <> Cells(r + 1, 3).Value And Not Cells(r, 3).Value = 0 Then
    Cells(r + 1, 12).Select
    Application.CommandBars("Standard").Controls("Autosum").Controls("Sum").Execute.SendKeys "{ENTER}"
    Application.SendKeys "{ENTER}"
End If
Next r
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TBH, I never used something like `SendKeys` in a VBA Macro. You should rather use something like

```
Cells(r + 1, 12).FormulaR1C1 = "=SUM(R1C12:R" & r & "C12)"
```

or

```
Cells(r + 1, 12).Formula = "=SUM(L1:L" & r & ")"
```

Your original question *why the AutoSum command is not working* I cannot answer.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I would have used your suggestion but I'm trying to SUM different sections of ranges and my starting Row is not going to be "1" but instead its going to be dynamic based on the If Statement.

Comment: Well, you can certainly accomplish your goal without using the command bar. Give it a try and come back here if it doesn't work out.